# Changing model id from integer to alphanumeric

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I changed by `id` in my model from the default `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` to `id = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True, default=random_string)`.

Here's the function for `random_string()`:

```
def random_string(chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    size = random.randrange(10, 15)
    return str(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))
```

it generates an alphanumeric string between 10 and 15 chars (e.g. `Kf4Idv9Wlmq`).

When I performed `makemigrations` and `migrate` on my local development server, there was no problem. However when I performed `makemigrations` and `migrate` on my remote server which uses `postgres`, it fired the error.

Any idea how I can fix this?

The error is:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to uuid
LINE 1: ..."post_post" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid, AL...
```

This may be related to my accompanying `PostScore` model:

```
class PostScore(models.Model):
    ...
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
```

The migration:

```
  Applying post.0004_auto_20180320_0841...SET CONSTRAINTS "comment_comment_post_id_357153e3_fk_post_post_id" IMMEDIATE; ALTER TABLE "comment_comment" DROP CONSTRAINT "comment_comment_post_id_357153e3_fk_post_post_id"; (params ())
SET CONSTRAINTS "post_postscore_post_id_224af0c0_fk_post_post_id" IMMEDIATE; ALTER TABLE "post_postscore" DROP CONSTRAINT "post_postscore_post_id_224af0c0_fk_post_post_id"; (params ())
SET CONSTRAINTS "post_advertisepost_post_ptr_id_d46585b8_fk_post_post_id" IMMEDIATE; ALTER TABLE "post_advertisepost" DROP CONSTRAINT "post_advertisepost_post_ptr_id_d46585b8_fk_post_post_id"; (params ())
SET CONSTRAINTS "profiles_inbox_post_id_367503fc_fk_post_post_id" IMMEDIATE; ALTER TABLE "profiles_inbox" DROP CONSTRAINT "profiles_inbox_post_id_367503fc_fk_post_post_id"; (params ())
ALTER TABLE "post_post" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid, ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT %s; (params [UUID('68a6adcc-1ee7-4c81-bd7e-eac4a78cb407')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zorgan/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to uuid
LINE 1: ..."post_post" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid, AL...
```

**EDIT**

I believe the problem is, before this I changed `id` to a UUID field. And I only applied the migrations to my development server, not my remote server. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't applied it manually, you have still created migration
post.0004_auto_20180320_0841. When you run manage.py migrate on your remote server, it applies (tries to apply) automatically.
The simplest approach is to edit this file under `/post/migrations/0004_auto_20180320_0841`
and change `models.UUIDField` to `models.CharField`.
It should work.